# CSS: Applying Multiple Media Queries

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, mobile

I have two `.css` files - one for desktop, and one for (the majority of) mobile devices. However, the CSS code applies to several `@media` conditions - and I cannot get them to work across all devices.

For example, for iPhone, the `@media` query looks something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 480px){
    /* iPhone styling */
}
```

If I wish to apply the same styles to a HTC One, I need to use:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (max-device-width:1920px){
    /* HTC One styling */
}
```

If I have two identical `.css` files - one with the first condition and one with the second - the website displays exactly how I want on both devices. However, when making a change this means that I need to edit multiple files.

I have tried combining the condition like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 480px),
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (max-device-width:1920px) {
    /* Generic mobile device styling */
}
```

but when testing on both the HTC and the iPhone, only the iPhone appears with my desired styling.

How can I get the same `.css` styling to apply to multiple `@media` conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) documentation, you shouldn't repeat `@media` after the coma. The following code should work:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 480px),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (max-device-width:1920px) {
    /* Generic mobile device styling */
}
```